# How can I update multiple values of a column by comparing with values of another column?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set the user_id by the corresponding id's . Something similar to-

```
update report set user_id (33077,11582,15872,32674,33077,19021,33477,33077,33477) where id in (18,216,23,334,232,2687,352,354,753)
```

Is it possible to do the above in a single query? The above query does not work.

Comment: No its not possible. You have to write like this UPDATE table_name set column1 = valuue1, column2 = value2,.....

Answer (score 1):

You can not do the way you are trying since the syntax is invalid, however you can use `case-when` in the update statement for setting multiple values something as

```
update affiliate_report_new
set 
user_id = 
case 
  when id = 18 then 33077
  when id = 216 then 11582
  when id = 23 then 15872
  when id = 334 then 32674
  .........
  .........
  when id = 753 then 33477
end 
where 
id in (18,216,23,334,232,2687,352,354,753)
```

Comment: This will be more time-consuming than running the query 9 times (no. of ids).

Comment: And if you have proper indexing it should not be, running multiple queries over the network is always considered to be bad considering the fact of data transfer and connecting multiple times instead of when things could be done with a single query. You can always use `explain select..` to analyze the query performace.